# Set a deletion action for a disclosure group without its contents

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to display a list of dynamic views and to show and hide an action row when I tap on a view in the list, so I used `DisclosureGroup`, but when I set a deletion action on the `ForEach` that contains the list of disclosure groups, it sets the deletion action on the children also, how can I set the deletion action only on the disclosure group label, without its contents?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { number in
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Button("Action") {}
                } label: {
                    Text("\(number)")
                }
            }
            .onDelete { _ in }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the `.deleteDisabled(true)` modifier on buttons which made them undeletable.